# why do I got this Error in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, exception, global-variables, declaration

[image]
hope you can see what am I missing. 
this error happened after I tried to get this variable from a public class globalv

```
public shared ip() as string
```

I deleted the class and I still get this error..

I do want my variable to be "global" so I will not make a new instance every time I need it. So I tried putting it at the top to make it global in the form.

```
Public Class Form1
#Region "variables"
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String)
    Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
    Dim stringOfRtb As String = rtb.Text
    Dim incoming() As String

    Dim ip() As String
#End Region

Private Sub btnSaveIP_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveIP.Click
    incoming = stringOfRtb.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray) ''vcrlf splitter

    ip = incoming(3).Split(":"c)
    txtSend.Text = "set ip local " & ip(1)
    End sub

Private Sub btnSettings_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSettings.Click
    ip = incoming(3).Split("="c)
    txtIP.Text = ip(1)
    End sub
```

Can you guys see what's wrong? It's been working before this.. :(

Comment: I did revert it back to the state when it was working, not control-z, I just edited it to what I remember it was working, no errors, but still it gives that error. help I can't see what's wrong :(

Comment: Exactly where does the Exception occur? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I don't know where, so I am lost. can you help me pinpoint it? although its running now, I moved my declarations to each subs. so its working fine, strOfRtb,incoming() and ip(). But it worked the same with strOfRtb and incoming() on top and ip() on each subs. When I made global class with shared ip(), that error started.

Comment: What is the exception?  I cannot see it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create a 'Global' variable for use throughout your application, it is better off in a module rather than a class. Just create a module in the root namespace of the application called something like "Globals", then declare the variable `Public ip() As String` (and assign it a value), then you should be able to call it from within that application.
Your problem actually seems to be coming though, from the fact that some of your value assigns to ip() are not giving a reference to which element of the array (such as `ip = incoming(3).Split(":"c)` should be something like `ip(1) = incoming(3).Split(":"c)`.

Comment: I created a module globalv and put your code, this seems to work for me. one thing, would ip() have the same value of string throughout? thanks!

Comment: Do you mean: Does ip() need to be an array? No, as far as I can see from the code you've uploaded, it does not need to be an array. You can just declare it as `Public ip As String` however for your own sake you should give it a better name than just "ip" (such as "clientIP" or "connectionIP" if it's going to be global or you might easily be confused when reading your code 1, 2 or 10 years down the track.

Comment: okay thanks, its not really an ip address rather just a variable that contains different data. loaded and replaced after clicking btnSettings event. thinking of "general" as its name. lol

Comment: Just remember with global variables, there is nearly always a better answer. If all it is doing is passing user input to another function, you're better off passing it directly rather than storing it globally and having the other function pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

This field declaration:

```
Dim stringOfRtb As String = rtb.Text
```

Sets `stringOfRtb` to the value of `rtb.Text`, *at the time* that the form is created. Either a) `rtb` hasn't been initialized yet, or b) `rtb.Text` may be `Nothing` at this point. It will never update itself to any other value, and so (for b) here:

```
incoming = stringOfRtb.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray)
```

Will be attempting to call `Split` on a non-existent string.

---

Those are my best guesses - but if neither is right, you need to learn to *debug*.

I assume (for b) that you're getting the error when you press the save button (that's an assumption because you haven't *told* us what you're doing to trigger the error).

If that's the case, then you need to set a breakpoint on the first line of the `btnSaveIP_Click` method and then press the button - you can then inspect the state of each variable and work out which one is `Nothing` and when.

Comment: only the declarations are on top. and that incoming code is on subs. also, the exception error pops right after I F5. thank you for explaining, added some knowledge to my brain :)